# jquery show input Search Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

HiEveryone :)
I'm looking for a jQuery plugin or tool that Show me Search Results EXACTLY like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4aBt.jpg

you can see the live demo at http://www.xda-developers.com (Find Your Device On Forum...)

I want to make exactly the same (I want to wenter 'phone name' and 'link' Manually). How should I do?

Please Help me to find out the result and source.

Mercy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advice using the **Chosen JQuery** [here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

Chosen is a JavaScript plugin that makes long, unwieldy select boxes much more user-friendly. It is currently available in both jQuery and Prototype flavors.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/). You can overwrite typeahead's css to display it however you want to.

Comment: +1 for typeahead: works very well, you can customize the view and there is a nice engine for suggestion